# one controller is loading views from other controllers, how and why?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following div in my index.html, whose controller is `MainCtrl`. This is the div used to load views from different controllers.

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
          <div ng-view></div>
      </div>
```

And these are my controllers:

```
.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider.
        when('/main', {
            templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl'
        }).
        when('/about', {
            templateUrl: 'views/about.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl'
        }).
        when('/services', {
            templateUrl: 'views/services.html',
            controller: 'ServicesCtrl'
        }).
        when('/contact', {
            templateUrl: 'views/contact.html',
            controller: 'ContactCtrl'
        }).
        otherwise({redirectTo: '/main'})

}])

.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('data/services.json').then(function(response){
        $scope.services = response.data;
    });
}])

.controller('ServicesCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('data/services.json').then(function(response){
        $scope.services = response.data;
    });
}])

.controller('ContactCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('data/locations.json').then(function(response){
        $scope.locations = response.data;
    });
}]);
```

It all works fine, but I do not understand how do all the views from different controllers get loaded automatically inside the `<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">` ?

So for example if I go to mysite/services, it loads services.html, even though its controller is ServicesCtrl.

It seems logical to me that it should only load the view from `MainCtrl`, which is `main.html` and `about.html`, yet it loads them all irrespective of controller names, how come?

Comment: your question doesn't make sense.  the **template** and the **controller** are two separate entities.  the route ***replaces the `<div ng-view>`*** with the HTML from the `templateUrl` and the controller from the `controller` line for each route.  for that matter, the `ng-controller` declaration is redundant, and could cause unexpected bugs.

Comment: As your routing says, when services, use services HTML and controller.  Take the ng-controller attribute off your div and let the routing loading the HTML and appropriate controller based upon your routeProvider.

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be an `ng-controller="MainCtrl"` because  the controllers for each route are defined in your routing configuration.

If you have this in your page then when `about` or `main` load you will actually initialize 2 instances of `MainCtrl`. One instance will be invoked by the router and the other by `ng-controller` and this can be problematic.

That being said you could have an outer controller but it wouldn't be the same as the ones used in the routes

Comment: I am doing some tutorials and this is the first project, I am new to angular and just wanted to know how come views from different controllers are being rendered appropriately. If I change the div controller for example to 'ContactCtrl', it will render views appropriately from 'MainCtrl' when home or about links are invoked.

Comment: the router does that. It parses the url and determines which template and controller to load ***inside*** `ng-view`

Comment: Yes, it is a template page and just this part is being changed based on links that are clicked.